# using same jquery on two different article tags on same page

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a Jquery file on two different article tags on the same page. These are the two different article tags,

First Article Tag,

```
    <article id="popupAbout" class="popupAbout"> <a id="popupAboutClose"><img src="../original/images/close.png" width="50" alt="" /></a>
  <h1>Maps of Arizona</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="photo-wrapper">
        <img class="image" id="image1" src="images/Wet.jpg"  height="450px" width="800px" alt="image 1"/>
        <img class="image" id="image2" src="images/Dens.jpg" height="450px" width="800px" alt="image 2"  />
        <img class="image" id="image3" src="images/Slope.jpg" height="450px" width="800px" alt="image 3"  />

        <!-- 
        <div id="transition-container"> This effect is not needed for this demo         
        </div>
        -->

        <img id="previous-btn" src="images/left_arrow.png" alt="Previous Button" />
        <img id="next-btn" src="images/right_arrow.png" alt="Next Button" />
    </div>
  </div>  
</article>
```

Second Article tag,

```
    <article id="popupProjects" class="popupProjects"> <a id="popupProjectsClose"><img src="../original/images/close.png" width="50" alt="" /></a>
  <h1>Maps of Four States</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="photo-wrapper">
        <img class="image" id="image1" src="images/3843_T_av6_4states.jpg"  height="450px" width="800px" alt="image 1"/>
        <img class="image" id="image2" src="images/4.jpg" height="450px" width="800px" alt="image 2"  />
        <img class="image" id="image3" src="images/beach6.jpg" height="450px" width="800px" alt="image 3"  />

        <!-- 
        <div id="transition-container"> This effect is not needed for this demo         
        </div>
        -->

        <img id="previous-btn" src="images/left_arrow.png" alt="Previous Button" />
        <img id="next-btn" src="images/right_arrow.png" alt="Next Button" />
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

As you can see, the tag contents are almost identical. I am using the same [Fade.js](http://jsfiddle.net/smaran/PgRfq/) on both. The first one is working fine, but the second one, i am only able to see the buttons and the image container, which is empty.

HELP!!!

Comment: What am I being voted down for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is potentially due to the fact you are reusing ids. All ids have to be unique but you are using the same ones multiple times (e.g. next-btn).

Change your jQuery to select by class instead of id and ensure that both articles contain the same classes.

Comment: @sam - you have two `<div id="container">` elements (for example).  jQuery simply does not know which one to choose and the out come may be unpredictable.

Comment: Sure, in your jQuery you have the `$('#id')` bits, those are telling the browser to find the elements on the page that has the id of "id" e.g. `$('#next-btn')` finds the next-btn element. If you were to remove the next-btn ids though, and instead put class="next-button" e.g. `<img class="next-button" src="images/right_arrow.png" alt="Next Button" />`, you could then change your jQuery to `$('.next-button')`, this would result in every element that has `class="next-button"` being selected instead of just the element that has the matching ID. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: ok, i updated my css in the link above (Fade.js), should i also modify it accordingly?

Comment: Yes, you will have to modify anything that was relying on the id tags so they use the class tags instead

Comment: I did, it has the same effect, First article tag working great, second one layout is good but empty. What do I do about the Image arrays in the JQuery which still uses Image Ids to be listed?

Comment: Hi @int0x90 i have changed all ids to class and also replaced the image array in jquery to class so that it takes all the ids as arrays like this,
var array = $(.image), but I am still able to get only the first article working. The second article does not display the image

Comment: @Sam007 can you post your newest code on pastebin.com please so I can have a look?

Comment: @int0x90 this is the html tags http://pastebin.com/03nPuAwi and this is the Fade.js http://pastebin.com/3Ru81YgM